# How to let Mediaplayer work with a fragment and array?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying implement mp3 player in my fragment that has several pages. The problem I'm facing now is that I can't let it work properly. The problem is that I'm trying to put audio files in an array with the page number i.e not all pages need to have an audio file.
When I run the app I get this error: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0`

I've commented where the error occurs. The pages that need to have an audio file are 1, 3, 13 and 16

This is what I've tried so far:

```
public class PageFragment_Sounds extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;
    private Button start, stop;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean synligtbillede = false;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    private int forwardTime = 5000;
    private int backwardTime = 5000;
    public static int oneTimeOnly = 0;
    int [] filer;

    public static PageFragment_Sounds newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        PageFragment_Sounds fragment = new PageFragment_Sounds();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_boenner, container, false);

        start = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);

        stop = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);

        filer = new int[18]; //I store the audio files here
        filer[3] = R.raw.rain;
        filer[1] = R.raw.thunder;
        filer[13] = R.raw.wave;
        filer[16] = R.raw.wind;

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(), filer[mPage]); //Here I get android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v == start){
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        else if(v == stop){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not storing valid resource IDs for all the positions in array. Make sure ***filer[mPage]*** results a valid raw resource ID.

Comment: But why aren't they valid resource IDs ? I've done the same for another int array with images, and that works fine